# Using jQuery/AJAX to run a php script on user click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a php script that I need to run using jQuery/AJAX when a user clicks a button.  I have a jQuery script that is supposed to fire when the user clicks the button.  However, the event isn't actually firing.  Can anyone assist me?

**instructor.php**

```
<div id="instructor">
    <?php
        echo "<img id=instructor_image src=" .$_SESSION["image"] .">";
        echo "<h1>" .$_SESSION["user"] ."</h1>";
        echo "<span><p>" .$_SESSION["program"] ."</p> - <h2>" .$_SESSION["role"] ."</h2></span>";
        echo "<a href=mailto:" .$_SESSION["email"] .">" .$_SESSION["email"] ."</a>";
    ?>
    <button class="button" name="logout" id="logout">Logout</button>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logout").on("click", function(){
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("../php/logout.php", "POST", true);
        ajax.send();
    })
})
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    require("../includes/header.php");

    $loggedout = "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `logged_in`=0 WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $loggedout);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    mysqli_close($connect);
    header("Location: ../pages/logged_out.php");
?>
```

The session is started in the header and yes, the header is called on every page.  I am also getting the following error on the `ajax.open()` line.  `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE:`

Comment: It is wrapped in a dom ready function, this event is part of a much larger js file and I didn't feel that it would be a good idea to include the entire script, but I'll wrap it in the function on here to avoid confusion.

Comment: The code looks fine without opening it myself and running it, just check the above 'ready' and also open up dev tools, and just check that the ajax is actually getting a successful load of '../php/logout.php' by looking at the requests your page is making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is something that is weird - `header("Location: ../pages/logged_out.php");` do you want to do redirect after user click? if so you should do it in your js.

i would change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logout").on("click", function(){
        $.post("../php/logout.php",{},function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace("../pages/logged_out.php");
            } else {
                //handle error
            }
        },'json');
    })
})
```

and php:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    ob_clean();
    $loggedout = "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `logged_in`=0 WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $loggedout);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    mysqli_close($connect);
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm running the script and then redirecting when the user clicks the button.  I'm unfamiliar with the `ob` functions.

Comment: Ob functions capture the output and either can store it in variable or echo it or discard. It is necessary to remove anything echo'ed to return proper json string. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php - more about output control functions

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
ajax.open("../php/logout.php", "POST", true);
```

is wrong. It is [`.open(method, url, async)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

> ```
> void open(
>    DOMString method,
>    DOMString url,
>    optional boolean async,
>    optional DOMString user,
>    optional DOMString password
> );
> ```

So change the code to

```
$("#logout").on("click", function(){
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "../php/logout.php", true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) console.log("done");
    }
    ajax.send();
});
```

and since you are using jQuery, you can just do

```
$("#logout").on("click", function(){
    $.post("../php/logout.php", function() { console.log("done") } );
});
```

Comment: So, instead of doing ajax.send(), I need to do the $.post statement?

Comment: You either replace the open line or you can just get rid of all the ajax code you have and replace it with one line.